# What stack is stackexchange chat built on?

Tags: discussion, web, chat, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is chat.stackoverflow.com off-the-shelf or in-house built?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68526/is-chat-stackoverflow-com-off-the-shelf-or-in-house-built)

I'm curious what the techonology stack for the StackExchange chat was built on. Does it use xmpp or did they roll their own? If they built it from scratch I'm curious as to why.

I was going to post this on meta, but i'm interested in the programming aspect of it, so I thought this would be a good spot.

Comment: If you were goint to post to meta, you would have noticed that it has been asked countless times: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=chat+technology - I couldn't find a definite answer specifically for chat, but y'know, duplicates, bounties, and all that.

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: So this will be moved to meta and closed as a duplicate there? What a depressing outlook :-)

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: So not even seasoned SO veterans bother with a search before asking, necessitating the whole migrate-and-close dance? What a depressing situation :-(

Comment: @Piskvor I wasn't complaining, just showing some empathy :-)

Comment: I wonder why none of the SO team ever answers any of the questions related to the chat. WTH??? So this one will be closed like all the others and STILL NO ANSWER.

Comment: What are you talking about? The dupe *has* an answer by a team member; one of the two who mainly built the chat, to be precise (me being the other one). And we've generally been very [open](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67891) [about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75045) [chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81100) [development](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66154). But all you did was ask the umpteenth "HOW CHAT WORKS? PLZ ANSWER KTHNX", ...

Comment: ... knowingly ask it on the wrong site and didn't bother searching, and then make up a story that "none of the SO team ever answers" so you have something to complain about. For my part, this behaviour is pretty close to trolling. If you have a *real* question, feel free to ask it, or drop in [the Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general); it's full of people who know the chat pretty well, often including me. If you just want to bitch around, then don't bother.