# is the SO chat open source?

Tags: discussion, chat, licensing

I am curious about the chat only. If not please recommend some alternatives that are comparable.

Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65321/what-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-chat

Comment: The second part of your question would be more appropriate for stackoverflow itself.

Comment: @Georg I really don't think Stack Overflow does product recommendations.

Comment: @badp's sockpuppet: That depends, I , on how you write your answer. There are already a few *What's a good library for ...?* questions, and I think they fit stackoverflow. But you're right, just asking for a finished product seems to be off-topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not FOSS, probably due to the tight integration with SE.

How about [IRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat)? :)

Comment: IRC is not a good alternative, for the same reasons the gave for why they didn't [choose to use IRC](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67879/what-does-chat-offer-that-irc-does-not/67891#67891).  It sure seems like this is something they could release in some way as FOSS, or at least in part.  The chat doesn't really seem to be part of their core functionality.

Comment: @Zoredache Feel free to come up with FOSS alternatives if you know of any

Comment: I don't know of any.  I have asked Jeff a couple times if they could provide this.  I even mentioned that I believe that a hosted version of their chat would be worth paying for in my opinion, and if the pricing was reasonable, and there where good privacy controls for a hosted version I believe I would start paying for a hosted version...