# Any plans on making the `chat` platform into an opensource platform like discourse?

Tags: discussion, chat, open-source

This is following Jeff's advice. I asked him:

> How about plans to making the [current SEN chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) into an opensource platform like Discourse?

To which he [quickly answered](https://meta.discourse.org/t/using-discourse-as-a-chat-application/3436/17?u=cawas):

> Don't know, you would have to ask Stack Exchange about that. Post on meta.stackexchange.com

I bet this is answered somewhere already, though. Links appreciated! :P

Answer (score 1):

Albeit not officially, this has indeed been [answered before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86587/is-the-so-chat-open-source). Since this chat is made explicitly for use with Stack Exchange, I doubt it'd make for a good open source candidate.

A quick search on GitHub revealed 3 fairly promising open source (team) chat apps, although none of them appear to be actively developed.

1. https://github.com/kandanapp/kandan
2. https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat
3. https://github.com/HashNuke/mogo-chat

You might also achieve something similar with closed apps like Slack or HipChat thanks to their extensive APIs.

Comment: Sometimes I ask non-practical questions... Not really looking for alternatives here, nor do I need one right now. I did look for alternatives to SEN in the past, though, and do you know what's the best one I've found? Discourse. :D I still think chat could be a great open source candidate.