# The nobodies of chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, gravatar

It seems that it's possible for gravatars and screen names to not be displayed properly in chat.  Check out the following screenie:

[image]

As you can see, the user chatting is [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97588/marco).  Marco came in first, followed by the user next to him (whose name I can't remember).  Marco's screen name and gravatar didn't appear when he posted a chat message.

This is the second time this has happened to me on chat, both times were fixed with a refresh but I thought I'd report it this time.

Comment: Huh.  Saw this too but figured it was just an issue with my internet connection at the time.

Comment: The ghosts in the machine.

Comment: Anonymous users?

Comment: @Gamecat: they had screen names and gravatars after I refreshed the page.

Comment: Andy, do you happen to have any extensions installed? In particular rchiang's greasemonkey script?

Comment: also, can you say *since when* you've seen this happen?

Comment: I have seen this (for a while) when the request is slow, they usually pop up in the end. Usually my torrents hehe

Comment: Had it happen to me also. I don't have any chat-specific scripts installed.

Comment: @balpha: This happened earlier today (just before I posted this question) and once before, within the last week or so.  I don't have any extensions installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

Back story: The information about users who are in the room when you open the page is inserted on page load. But the client is responsible for asking the server for the information about users who a) enter afterwards, or b) who aren't there anymore, but have talked recently and thus have messages visible.

There was an issue that caused the information retrieval to fail if the number of yet-unknown users was too high. This issue is now resolved.

Comment: Good stuff, and fast work :-)