# Details on Stackoverflow's chat implementation

Tags: discussion, chat, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What technologies were used to build the chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65321/what-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-chat)

Has the technology behind SO chat functionality been discussed. I would love to get more details about their architecture and tech stack behind the chat server implementation.

Comment: Question belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com. Actually, the answer to the question itself is probably meta.stackoverflow.com.