# Administer chat room when owner is absent

Tags: discussion, chat

Is there a way to administer a chat room, such as change it's title or add feed items, when owner is usually absent?

Comment: I would start with posting a link to the chatroom in question when you post a MSO post about it ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A moderator can always do that, so if you see one around (the people with blue user names) ask them, or flag some message in the room for moderator attention and explain the issue. Also note that if the room owner doesn't show up for a while, a new one will (under certain conditions) be automatically appointed: [Chat clean up & owner rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80205/chat-clean-up-owner-rules/80208#80208)