# How can the automatically created beta site chat rooms get owners?

Tags: support, chat, beta-phase

I am participating in the private beta for a new stack exchange site. I entered [the automatically created chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2250/cognitive-sciences) to make myself available to help discuss site issues, flag/edit questions, help new users, etc.

[This room has no owners](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2250/cognitive-sciences). I guess these rooms are created automatically with new beta sites now? How can an owner be added? Who gets to be the owner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to ask a moderator to grant someone the owner privileges. At least that's what I did when Skeptics was a new site and I wanted to add a meta question feed to the chat room.

With the large number of moderators we have now there is a high chance that one of the users of the new site already is a moderator and can appoint room owners. If that isn't the case and a room owner is needed, you can flag for moderator attention in chat (not the spam/offensive flag). For most stuff you don't need a room owner, so it doesn't matter that much if you don't have one.

There is also an automatic way that users can become room owners I think, but I have no idea how that one works.

Comment: Re your last paragraph: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80205/chat-clean-up-owner-rules/80208#80208

Answer (score 3):

If a room has no active owners, it will, given time, automatically appoint users it deems active enough.