# May I be a chat owner/administrator for the MySQL chat room?

Tags: support, chat, room-owner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Chat clean up & owner rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80205/chat-clean-up-owner-rules)

The current owner of [The MySQL chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql) ([info](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/592/mysql)) hasn't showed up for as long as I've been frequenting the room.  I'm the most active member of the (usually-quiet) room.

I would like to request that I be made an owner/administrator for this handy chat.

Should I take a responsibility test of some sort, or do you just need to do a background check or something?

**Edit:** looks like there is an automated system in place to deal with this already - however, the traffic in the MySQL chat room isn't high enough to justify me saying enough lines to pass the message thresholds.

I'm not about to start spamming the chat room with messages (any more than I already do, that is), so my request still stands.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80205/chat-clean-up-owner-rules

Comment: ...um, by which I mean, of _course_ there is a background check. Just submit your name, address, phone, email, DOB, SSN, bank account numbers, all aliases and usernames, passwords, credit reports, and an essay detailing your deepest, darkest fears and I'll get right on that. :-P

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky hey, thanks for the link!  I've edited the question, and forwarded all my personal information to you!  Let me know if I make the cut! :-D

Comment: don't forget SSH keys... and possibly add a "please" into the title ;)