# Can the sound come from the correct tab, please?

Tags: feature-request, chat, audio

The chat notification sounds originate from the chat opened first. This quite fine for most cases, but now that Chrome displays the tab which rang the bell, I'm horribly confused when I have not been pinged in the room I first joined, especially when I have quite a few chat tabs open at once.

Could the sound come from the chat where I was pinged, assuming I have the page open in another tab?

Comment: Until I got half way into this I thought you had a *really* fancy screen

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post (Multiple chat tabs)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85034/multiple-chat-tabs), there is only one chat client that handles the polling, which get's the notifications and make the sound. So the originating tab is always the first tab.

I guess they can implement something to originate the sound from the correct tab, but does it worth the headache?